# Реализовать функцию createObject()

Tags: объекты, javascript

Реализовать функцию `createObject(arrOfKeys, arrOfData)`, которая принимает аргументами
два массива и возвращает объект, в котором названия ключей - это строки из массива 
`arrOfKeys`, а значения - элементы из массива `arrOfData`. В ключ, стоящий на первом 
месте массива `arrOfKeys`, должно быть записано значение, стоящее на первом месте `arrOfData`.
 Если данных меньше, чем ключей, заполняй значения ключей как undefined.

```
var map = {};
var event=['yres1','yres2'];
var phi=['1','3'];
function createObject(event, phi) {
  map[event] = phi;
  return map;
}
createObject(event,phi);
```

Но пишет ошибку:

> Замечание:
>
> Функция createObject не возвращает {},
> как ожидалось, при таком вызове:
> createObject([], []).

Comment: @Yres, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы создали какое-то окружение для запуска вашей функции. Его быть не должно. Т.е. все, что до слова `function`, удалите.
2. А теперь смотрите, что у вас делает функция. Переменную `map` необходимо объявить внутри функции, т.е. создать объект, который впоследствии вернуть в качестве результата функции.
3. Далее, `map[event]` у вас создает свойство, одно, типа массив и значение у него массив. В задании просят создать объект, у которого будет столько свойств, сколько в первом массиве с соответствующими значениями из второго массива.

Вот вам тесты:

```
function createObject(arrOfKeys, arrOfData){
  ....
}
var o1 = createObject([],[]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(o1)==="{}"?"ok":"error");
var o2 = createObject(["a"],["b"]);
console.log(o2.a==="b"?"ok":"error");
var o3 = createObject(["a","b","c"],["1","2","3"]);
coonsole.log(JSON.stringify(o3)==='{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}'?"ok":"error");
var o4 = createObject(["a"],[]);
console.log(o4.hasOwnProperty("a")&&o4.a===undefined?"ok":"error");
```

Получите четыре, ну хотя бы три раза "ok" в консоли, значит идете верным путем.

Comment: Ага, понял. Мап в функцию добавил... значит циклик, наверное, нужен размерностю равной длине массива, да?

Вот так получается, да?

    function createObject(event, phi) {
     var map = {};
     for(i=0; i<event.length; i++)
     map[event[i]] = phi[i];
     return map;
    }

Comment: @Yres, ага. Все верно. Больше не ругаются? ;)